# Get next element in stack with a absolute position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

We have the next markup:

```
<div class="box">
    <div id="item1">1</div>
    <div id="item2">2</div>
    <div id="item3">3</div>
</div>
```

Divs with id item1, item2, item3, are positioned absolutely. 
By css item2 moved more left than item3.

Example is here `http://jsfiddle.net/tto8ymqa/`

The `$('#item1').next()` will return $('#item2')
How to get visual NEXT element?

If explanation is not understandable please ask me :)

Comment: I think you would need to compare offsets to do that

Comment: More specifically, you'll want a function that could sort your jquery object in the order according to offsets.. you need help with that?

Comment: I think I will handle this ptoblem! Strange but I did not think about offset! Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example function:

http://jsfiddle.net/tto8ymqa/2/

#### js

```
var domOrder, visualOrder;
$(function() {
   domOrder = $(".box").find("DIV");
   getVisualOrder();  
})

function getVisualOrder() {
    visualOrder = domOrder.sort(function(a,b) {
        return $(a).offset().left-$(b).offset().left;
    });    
    console.log(visualOrder);
}
```

good luck!

Comment: I tried to use this order function but I occure little bug. If I try to sort collection which have multiple rows sorting is incorrect because last item in previous row have bigger offset than first item in next row. I thought that for every next row element we have to add length of row multipled on row number to item offset but I confused how do it correctly. Becuse everytime items are mixed.

Comment: could you add your case to a fiddle where I can see it?